# Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'

Tags: android, gradle, libgdx, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am not able to solve the following error

```
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zzqx.class
```

I do know the problem lies with the conflicting versions but I don't know gradle that well to solve it.

My android dependencies are:

```
 dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.0'

        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:10.0.0'
        compile project(':BaseGameUtils')



    }
```

How am I supposed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to carefully combine the previous similar types of questions to get the answer.I had to add the following line to the configuration block in `build.gradle`

```
 all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-plus'
```

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted otherwise, people will keep coming to help.

Comment: looks like I'm still a noob, it says you can accept your answer in 2 days